# check if im going out of bounds in a maze

Tags: java

I have a 2D array thats 4x4 for now and I already have a method to check if there is a wall and right now I am trying to write the method that checks if the player goes out of bounds of the maze.  Basically what I need is a boolean method that just checks if the possible new position of the player is going to be out of bounds in the 2d array or not.  this is what I have so far I know it doesnt work because im trying to compare a string with an integer operator.  I need something that will compare the actual index of the possible new position to the legth of the 2d array and return true if its out of bounds and false if its okay for the player to move there.

```
//check to see if youre going out of bounds
    public Boolean isOutOfBounds(int x, int y, String d){
        if(d.equalsIgnoreCase("N")){

            y--;
            if(maze[x][y] > maze.length){
                //output "cannot go this way" from text class
            }
        }
    }
```

the parameters are the original position of the player and the direction they are trying to go

Comment: why do you compare the content of the cell and not the coordinate?

Comment: I know thats what the problem is.   how do I compare the actual coordinate and not the contents?

Comment: what are the coordinate in you code?

Comment: If they are going right x++,left x--, up y++ and down y-- , then compare the new position with your maze length,...

Comment: I dont understand what youre asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need something like this:

```java
public Boolean isOutOfBounds(int x, int y, String d){
    if(d.equalsIgnoreCase("N")){
        y--;
    }
    if(d.equalsIgnoreCase("S")){
        y++;
    }
    if(d.equalsIgnoreCase("E")){
        x--;
    }
    if(d.equalsIgnoreCase("W")){
        x++;
    }
    return ! (x >= 0 && x < maze.length &&  y >= 0 && y < maze.length);
}
```